# Use EAV from one table and join to another table

Tags: jquery, db2

I have a table called search that has the following records:

search

```
SID     Parameter       Value
100     firstname       John
100     middle          
100     lastname        Doe
100     dateOfBirth     
100     firstname       Jon
100     middle          
100     lastname        Doe
100     dateOfBirth     
100     firstname       Homer
100     middle          
100     lastname        Doe
100     dateOfBirth
```

This is basically one search for John% Doe, Jon% Doe or Homer% Doe.

My customer table is :

```
CustomerID   FirstName   LastName   dateOfBirth
1            Jonathan    Doe
2            Johny       Doe
3            Jonnie      Doe
4            Homer       Doe
5            Marge       S
```

Then, I need to join the search table to get the all the customers that satisfy these conditions.

```
(
AND UPPER( sometable.lastname ) = 'DOE'
AND UPPER( sometable.firstname ) like 'JOHN%'  
)
OR
(
AND UPPER( sometable.lastname ) = 'DOE'
AND UPPER( sometable.firstname ) like 'Jon%'  
)
OR
(
AND UPPER( sometable.lastname ) = 'DOE'
AND UPPER( sometable.firstname ) like 'Homer%'  
)
```

I am not sure how pivot functionality works in db2. I must add that I know the SID=100 in advance. So, I just need those values only for 100.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
/*
WITH 
  SEARCH (SID, Parameter, Value) AS 
(
VALUES
  (100, 'firstname', 'John')
, (100, 'middle', '')    
, (100, 'lastname', 'Doe')
, (100, 'dateOfBirth', '')   
, (100, 'firstname', 'Jon')
, (100, 'middle', '')
, (100, 'lastname', 'Doe')
, (100, 'dateOfBirth', '')
, (100, 'firstname', 'Homer')
, (100, 'middle', '')
, (100, 'lastname', 'Doe')
, (100, 'dateOfBirth', '')
)
, CUSTOMER (CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, dateOfBirth) AS
(
VALUES
  (1, 'Jonathan', 'Doe', '')
, (2, 'Johny', 'Doe', '')
, (3, 'Jonnie', 'Doe', '')
, (4, 'Homer', 'Doe', '')
, (5, 'Marge', 'S', '')
)
*/
SELECT * 
FROM CUSTOMER C
WHERE 
    EXISTS 
(
SELECT 1
FROM SEARCH S
WHERE S.SID=100 AND S.PARAMETER='firstname' AND C.FIRSTNAME LIKE S.VALUE||'%'
)
AND EXISTS 
(
SELECT 1
FROM SEARCH S
WHERE S.SID=100 AND S.PARAMETER='lastname' AND C.LASTNAME=S.VALUE
);
```

You may uncomment the block with your test data commented out and run the statement as is. You may change the test data as well to check.